# Upload only field

Tags: file-uploads, fieldtype, uploads

Is there a setting for the file-fieldtype or a third-party fieldtype that allows only to upload a file (and NOT browse existing ones).

The goal is that certain member groups are only supposed to add files.

Answer (score 1):

Channel Files will probably do what you're looking to do. The "Limit Stored Files by Author" setting is probably what you're looking for, here's a screenshot of the fieldtype settings screen: http://www.devdemon.com/images/products/30/fieldtype.jpg

You can buy it here: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/channel-files

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered the Safecracker File fieldtype which perfectly fits the bill.

That said, I just read it has been removed in 2.7 ...